# Remote editing of nginx conf file present in an AWS ec2 instance

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, file-permissions

So, I have installed nginx in an EC2 instance that is running a RHEL OS. Everything is fine, except that I can't remotely edit the nginix conf file using SFTP client Cyberduck.

The problem is AWS EC2 seems to have a restriction on SFTP using root user.  I installed nginx with sudo, guess it is saving the conf files with root priviledges. So when I sftp using ec2-user (since root is not allowed), Cyberduck simply complains that you can not save the file because conf file is owned by root.
So nginx developers out there, how do you handle this situation? For me it is really tedious to edit the conf file via ssh and vi editor in EC2 instance. That is why I prefer to edit it locally and sync. But I am not sure how to achieve this. I tried giving access to the conf folder to the ec2-user as per [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487527/give-specific-user-permission-to-write-to-a-folder-using-w-notation) too. But invain!.  Any help is appreciated.

PS: I installed the nginx using sources and here is the configure command with options I used:

```
./configure --sbin-path=/usr/bin/nginx --conf-path=/home/ec2-user/conf/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path==/var/log/nginx/access.log --with-pcre --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_v2_module
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out that we can change the permissions of the root folder from where nginx is serving its contents, in this case /var/share/nginx/html to 777. Also ensure the permissions for files inside this folder have 666 permission.
sudo chmod 777 /var/share/nginx/html
sudo chmod 666 /var/share/nginx/html/*

Also enabled read/write permissions for all users for the configuration files as well. This enabled me remote editing the configs as well as html contents.